# shift values from another column python pandas to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and facing and issue with the following:

a) How do I shift right the values from Rank to Total with values from Rank to Bronze if the total containing `NAN` at column Total

b) How to fill the missing value of Rank (After the shift value) to a value derived from the row above it.

Issue:

```
    Rank    NOC Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total
0   1   United States (USA) 46  37  38  121
1   2   Argentina (ARG) 3   1   0   4
2   3   Denmark (DEN)   2   6   7   15
3   4   Sweden (SWE)    2   6   3   11
4   5   South Africa (RSA)  2   6   2   10
5   6   Sweden (SWE)    2   6   3   11
**6 Tajikistan (TJK)    1   0   0   1   NaN**
7   7   Malaysia (MAS)  0   4   1   5
```

Expected Outcome:

```
    Rank    NOC Gold    Silver  Bronze  Total
[0  1   United States (USA) 46  37  38  121
1   2   Argentina (ARG) 3   1   0   4
2   3   Denmark (DEN)   2   6   7   15
3   4   Sweden (SWE)    2   6   3   11
4   5   South Africa (RSA)  2   6   2   10
5   6   Sweden (SWE)    2   6   3   11
**6 6   Tajikistan (TJK)    1   0   0   1**
7   7   Malaysia (MAS)  0   4   1   5]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DJM6.png)

Comment: If this data is in a table format, it would be much easier to read and increase the probability of a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by adding up the Gold, Silver and Bronze (with some weights to ensure gold count more any number of silvers etc.) then you can use [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
In [11]: (df["Gold"] * 10000 + df["Silver"] * 100 + df["Bronze"])
Out[11]:
0    463738
1     30100
2     20607
3     20603
4     20602
5     20603
6     10000
7       401
dtype: int64

In [12]: (df["Gold"] * 10000 + df["Silver"] * 100 + df["Bronze"]).rank(method='first', ascending=False)
Out[12]:
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    6.0
5    5.0
6    7.0
7    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Agreed. But doesn't resolve the second issue where 'Tajikistan' should also be ranked the same as 'Sweden'

Comment: @KaSulaiman that's the `method='first'` kwarg, you don't need to pick a  winner. If you don't pass that kwarg, they tie at 4.5. i.e. just use `.rank(ascending=False)`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. It works but not sure how optimised it is. As long the answer is correct for me.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import re

# Step 1
# Cleanup values within NOC and Rank. Start off with changing the values within Total
# Replace the value of Total which is Null to NaN

df.loc[:, 'Total2'] = df['Total'].isnull()

# Step 2
# Filter Total equal to Nan and shift the row values from Rank to Total - Rank to Bronze

df.ix[df.Total2 == True, 'Total'] = df['Bronze']
df.ix[df.Total2 == True, 'Bronze'] = df['Silver']
df.ix[df.Total2 == True, 'Silver'] = df['Gold']
df.ix[df.Total2 == True, 'Gold'] = df['NOC']
df.ix[df.Total2 == True, 'NOC'] = df['Rank']

# Step 3
# Clean up the Rank column. Create a new column which reveal only digit value

df['Rank2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rank'], errors='coerce')
df['fill_forward'] = df['Rank2'].fillna(method='ffill')
del df['Rank']
del df['Rank2']
del df['Total2']
df = df.rename(columns={'fill_forward': 'Rank'})
```